# Create multi-N array matrixes without foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, phpunit

Typical @dataProvider method in PHPunit can look like this:

```
return [
    [const1,    true],
    [const2,    true],
    [const3,    true],

    [const1,    false],
    [const2,    false],
    [const3,    false],
];
```

Which is actually a multiply of [const1, const2, const3] onto [true, false]. When we have not so many values it's ok to hardcode it.

But when we have many items in each "axis" it becomes too long list of repeating values. One possible solution is one foreach for each "axis". But what if we have many "axis"es?

So the question is — does somebody knows some elegant way of creating multi-axis-multi-valued arrays for this case?

tnx.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [['const1','const2','const3'], [true, false]];

$count     = array_map('count', $array);
$finalSize = array_product($count);
$arraySize = count($array);
$output    = array_fill(0, $finalSize, []);
$i = 0;
$c = 0;
for (; $i < $finalSize; $i++) {
    for ($c = 0; $c < $arraySize; $c++) {
        $output[$i][] = $array[$c][$i % $count[$c]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Jimish, I know about fors and foreaches. I just want to try without them. Also your solution is for only two "axises" — it's hardcoded :(